# My bit rotation in MIPS doesn't work as expected

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips, bit-shift

I'm trying to solve a problem, but at first I'm testing `rol` instruction, and I'm totally sure I'm doing something very silly which makes my test not correct.

Here's a snippet:

```
    li $t0, 101 ## our data 
    li $t1, 32 ## our loop because we will rotate 32 times later
loop: 
    ## whatever the bit is, just print it or put it inside the asciiz
    ## and print it later, after we finish rotating,
    ## so we rotate starting with the first bit,
    ## and we put it as the first bit lsb

    ## first we rotate##
    rol $t2, $t0, 1 ## rotate and store the new rotated inside $t7
    and $t3, $t2, 1 ## now we AND to check our lsb if it one or not

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t3 ## Print the result of AND
    syscall
```

What I'm basically trying to do, is to rotate the MSB of my `t0` to the LSB and then ANDing it with 1. However, what I'm getting is 0 all the time.

I hope someone could enlighten me about my mistake and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSB of `101` when represented on 32 bits is zero, so a zero result is correct. If you load for example `0x80000000` you will get `1` as result. Note that `rol` is a pseudoinstruction that the assembler will replace with `srl; sll; or` sequence so depending on what you really want to do, it might be more efficient do use the real instructions as appropriate. For example in your case, a single `srl $t3, $t0, 31` will give the same result as the `rol; and` sequence.

Comment: Note: Rotate is a real instruction that was introduced in the MIPS32R2 revision of the MIPS Architecture (`ROTR`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any jump to `loop` in your code. How can the loop run?

If the whole code below the `loop` label is the loop content then you're rotating without storing the result to $t0, so the loop always return `(101 rol 1) and 1`

```
li $t0, 101 ## our data
## where did you store the new rotated value to $t0? If not, it's always 101
rol $t2, $t0, 1 ## $t2 = $t0 rol 1 = 101 rol 1 = 202
and $t3, $t2, 1 ## $t3 = $t2 and 1 = 202 and 1 = 0
```